i cant apply my custom provider at Keycloak
I was installed keycloak by helm chart[bitnami]
But I can't apply customer providers, theme ...
Name and Version
bitnami/keycloak
#values.yaml

extraVolumes:
    - name: keycloak-spi-pv
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: keycloak-spi-pvc
extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: keycloak-spi-pv
      mountPath: /mydir
This is my first time using Keycloak. And I am not good at English. I ask for your understanding

When the pod starts, I can see the directory in /mydir.
To custom user providers apply,
The file must be placed in /opt/bitnami/keycloak
If I edit the additional volume mount path to [/opt/bitnami/keycloak].
The keycloak install scripts(?) are not working. It seems to have been overwritten by the persistent volume.
I used the container below:
- Name: init-spi
  Image: busybox
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  Command: ["/bin/sh"]
  args: [-c], cp -R /mydir/* /opt/bitnami / keycloak /"]
  Mount Volume:
  - name : keycloak-spi- pv
    mountPath: /mydir
  Security Context:
    Run as user: 1001
    RunAsGroup: 1001

But again, it didn't work.
Unable to create cp: '/opt/bitnami/keycloak' directory, no such file or directory.
The directory cannot be created because the main container (keycloak installation scripts) has not started.
How do I apply for a custom user provider??
Or is there a way to restart Keycloak without deleting the pod?
If possible, I would like to copy the file directly to the directory after the Keycloak pod is executed.
Or if there is a good way, please advise.
++++++++++
And also can see when tried kc.sh start-dev.
I need to find out how to reload keycloak instead delete the pod
keycloak@keycloak-0:/opt/bitnami/keycloak$ kc.sh start-dev
Appending additional Java properties to JAVA_OPTS: -Djgroups.dns.query=keycloak-headless.keycloak.svc.cluster.local
Updating the configuration and installing your custom providers, if any. Please wait.
2024-08-09 01:25:40,317 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (build-16) KC-SERVICES0047: metrics (org.jboss.aerogear.keycloak.metrics.MetricsEndpointFactory) is implementing the internal SPI realm-restapi-extension. This SPI is internal and may change without notice
2024-08-09 01:25:41,064 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (build-16) KC-SERVICES0047: metrics-listener (org.jboss.aerogear.keycloak.metrics.MetricsEventListenerFactory) is implementing the internal SPI eventsListener. This SPI is in

2024-08-09 01:26:04,994 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (development) mode
2024-08-09 01:26:04,994 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start caches
2024-08-09 01:26:04,995 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: Unable to start JGroups Channel
2024-08-09 01:26:04,995 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Unable to start JGroups Channel
2024-08-09 01:26:04,996 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Unable to start JGroups Channel
2024-08-09 01:26:04,997 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: No available port to bind to in range [7800 .. 7800]
2024-08-09 01:26:04,998 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option

. Also you can use '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.


This commit https://github.com/bitnami/charts/commit/9de041c92e2788a108631052aa5401a9469e3592 has made it possible to add your providers with at initContainer.
initContainers: |
    - name: keycloak-plugin
      image: my-plugin
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      command:
        - sh
      args:
        - -c
        - |
          echo "Copying module..."
          cp -r /module/* /emptydir/app-providers-dir
      volumeMounts:
        - name: empty-dir
          mountPath: /emptydir

